# Kibana: How to get list of unique entries of one field?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I want to get a list of all unique entires in one field in an
elasticsearch-database.

The field I am looking for is:

```
friendly_name
```

I am aware of how to visualize the unique count of a field when visualizing.
Explained here: https://www.timroes.de/2015/02/07/kibana-4-tutorial-part-3-visualize/

But I want a list of all.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a Data visualization with a terms aggregation on your field would give you the unique list (and the count).

Answer (score -1):

You might want to check my answer on [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31385530/how-to-list-unique-values-of-a-particular-field-in-kibana). If I am getting your requirements right, that is exactly what you're looking for.

The OP of that question says that it works but unfortunately he has not marked it right or upvote it as of now.