# "Visualize" Not in Kibana Menu Bar?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm seeking to get a count of unique field values in Kibana.

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31385530/how-to-list-unique-values-of-a-particular-field-in-kibana) says to go to `Visualize -> Data Table`:

[image]

But on my Kibana instance, "Visualize" is not shown in the navbar:

[image]

What is the correct way for me to access `Visualize -> Data Table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version you are looking is too old, things have changed.

To do aggregations you need to go to Dashboards and create a table under visualizations (you can click the blue "Create Visualization" button, or go to aggregation based and select data table).

[image]